# Ничего не выводит в консоль

Tags: node.js

Использую bash.

```js
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    function log() {
        console.log(3);
    }
    log();
})

server.listen(6000, () => {})
```

Comment: чтобы это кодилище вывело что-то в консоль - к нему нужно сделать запрос. `curl http://localhost:6000`. ты бы лучше обучалок посмотрел/почитал, чем на so спамить

Comment: @nörbörnën, перехожу на localhost:6000, в консоли все равно ничего не появляется.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Посмотрите на страницу браузера, там должен быть класс ошибки ERR_UNSAFE_PORT.

Если смените порт, будет выводить. Похоже, браузер просто блокирует этот порт и запрос не доходит до сервера.

См. https://superuser.com/questions/188058/which-ports-are-considered-unsafe-by-chrome.